# How do I scroll to a certain component in Java FX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I need to scroll down to a certain label component in Java FX. How do I do that ? I have ids attached to label component.

```
<ScrollPane>
    <VBox fx:id="menuItemsBox">
        <Label text="....."/>
        <Label text="....."/>
        <Label text="....."/>
        ....
        <Label text="....."/>
   </VBox>
</ScrollPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the scrollPane's `vValue` to the Node's `LayoutY` value. Since the [`setVvlaue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setVvalue-double-) accepts value between `0.0 to 1.0`, you need to have computation to range your input according to it.

```
scrollPane.setVvalue(/*Some Computation*/);
```

This must be set after the stage's [`isShowing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#isShowing--) is `true`.

**Complete Example**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();
        VBox box = new VBox();
        IntStream.range(1, 10).mapToObj(i -> new Label("Label" + i)).forEach(box.getChildren()::add);
        pane.setContent(box);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 50);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Logic to scroll to the nth child
        Bounds bounds = pane.getViewportBounds();
        // get(3) is the index to `label4`.
        // You can change it to any label you want
        pane.setVvalue(box.getChildren().get(3).getLayoutY() * 
                             (1/(box.getHeight()-bounds.getHeight())));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Label` component inside of `Vbox` inside `Scollpane` always gives me `0.0` for layoutY... how do I find the vertical position of a node ? Also setting vvalue had no effect..

Comment: is this not supposed to be there in initialize() method of controller ? i need to do this by default on page load .. where is the best way to place this code ?>

Comment: No it is not. Initialize() is called before the layout is actually shown on the scene. You can expose a method from the controller and call it after the FXML has been loaded.

Comment: is there anything for **smooth scrolling** to a component inside scroll pane ?

Comment: Please create a separate question in case you have further issues.

Comment: This is a great solution to scroll child to the top of the scrollpane's viewport, but how about to scroll the child to the bottom of the viewport if the child is outside to the bottom?