# JavaFX - How to programmatically scroll a ScrollPane upon button click?

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

I wanted to know if there was any "easy" way I can set the vertical scroll-bar to be "scrolled" a specific amount upon a button press, or really upon any event at all.

For example, I have an application which has a side bar and one of the options on the sidebar is Settings. Settings has sub items, and I wanted to add the functionality to click on one of the sub items and it will open the Settings page and automatically scroll down to that specific point on the page where that sub item is located.

Comment: Manipulate the [`ScrollPane#vvalue`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vvalueProperty) property.

Comment: This was the answer, thank you! I'm not sure how to set it as the answer for the thread, though.

Comment: As my "answer" was a comment, there is no way to accept it. However, I posted a community wiki answer that you can accept to mark the question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically scroll a `ScrollPane` vertically simply manipulate the [`vvalue`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vvalueProperty) property. Here's the documentation of that property:

> The current vertical scroll position of the ScrollPane. This value may be set by the application to scroll the view programatically. The ScrollPane will update this value whenever the viewport is scrolled or panned by the user. This value must always be within the range of `vmin` to `vmax`. When `vvalue` equals `vmin`, the contained node is positioned so that its layoutBounds `minY` is visible. When `vvalue` equals `vmax`, the contained node is positioned so that its layoutBounds `maxY` is visible. When `vvalue` is between `vmin` and `vmax`, the contained node is positioned proportionally between layoutBounds `minY` and layoutBounds `maxY`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29330714/11268550) solution:

```
Bounds bounds = pane.getViewportBounds();
pane.setVvalue(box.getChildren().get(x).getLayoutY() * 
                             (1/(box.getHeight()-bounds.getHeight())));
```

The `pane` is the ScrollPane. The `box` is the Pane holding the nodes to scroll to. `x` would by the child node to scroll to.