# JavaFX - Change ScrollPane's vvalue to a specific amount based on Window size

Tags: java, javafx, dynamic, window

I have an application which has a side bar, and one of the items in the sidebar is a Settings option. This option in the side bar has many sub-items, these items being the different headers on the Settings page. This page which contains every Settings item, and I am looking for a way to set the ScrollPane's vvalue of this window based on which sub-item was selected so that the item they selected will be at the very top of the screen.

I have been successful with hard coding the vvalue, of course, but once the size of the window changes it is no longer scrolled down to the exact point in which I want it to be. Below you can see an image of my application on the Settings page. Based on the image, if the user would select the Setting2 option in the sub menu, I would want the ScrollPane's vvalue to change where the Setting2 header was at the very top of the screen no matter what the size of the application window is.

[image]

Comment: Could you put the Settings objects on the right into a ListView and use  `scrollTo(object)` to scroll to the appropriate setting?

Comment: Related question: [How do I scroll to a certain component in Java FX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330435/how-do-i-scroll-to-a-certain-component-in-java-fx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @jewelsea 's approach I was able to fix my problem, thanks!

His answer was:

Could you put the Settings objects on the right into a ListView and use scrollTo(object) to scroll to the appropriate setting?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the value to assign to the `vvalue` property based on the position of the top in the `content` node (`posY`), the total height of the content (`contentHeight`) and the height of `ScrollPane.viewport` (`viewportHeight`):

```
vvalue = topY / (contentHeight - viewportHeight)
```

(that is assuming you haven't changed `vmax` and `vmin`)

You may need to use [`Node.localToParent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToParent(javafx.geometry.Point2D)) multiple times to compute the correct position in coordinates of the `content` node; It needs to be applied to the node itself and every ancestor up to the child of the `content` node.

Comment: So in this case, is topY = vmax?

Comment: @piggy topY is the `y` coordinate of the point of the content node that is supposed to be positioned at the top of the viewport. I just realized that you need to divide instead of multiply; sorry for that. Basically the changing `vvalue` in `[vmin, vmax]` moves the bottom of the content node in a linear fassion. `contentHeight - viewportHeight` is the distance the bottom of the content is below the bottom of the viewport when you scroll to the very top.

Comment: By default that range is `vmax = 1` and `vmin = 0` which I recommend keeping